# Safari Mac doesn't load websites and shows crashed images

Tags: macos, safari

I'm really struggling with my Safari on Macbook and I'm getting frustrated and angry.
I use Macbook Air 13" 2015, Catalina 10.15.7, Safari 14.0
Some websites doesn't load at all, the error is "Safari can't find the server". And some load crashed images. The thing is that it ONLY happens in Safari. I instantly open the same pages in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and ALL of them load everything perfect, no errors, no problems with images.
What I've done already with Google help:

1. Develop - Empty Caches
2. sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
3. Preferences - Privacy - Manage Website Data - Remove All

Sometimes it helps but after browsing for like 20-60 minutes the problems repeat again. And clearing data every 30 minutes irritates me because I get logged out everywhere. I can't google the solution, please, help me. Why other browsers don't have these errors? What can I do except that move to Firefox or Chrome?
[image]
[image]

Comment: The issue is clearly not with wifi, websites, etc. It is something with Safari only.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome both use DNS over HTTPS (Safari doesn't use it yet)  As a test, try [disabling it in Firefox/Chrome](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-in-your-web-browser-1841909057) and if the problem continues, it will be related to your  your DNS settings/servers.

Comment: @Allan I looked at preferences - "Use DNS over HTTPS" is not checked in Chrome and it loads everything fine. I just added 1.1.1.1 in DNS setting on my Mac and now Safari works too. But is it safe to use public DNS like Cloudflare?

Comment: Safe?  Yes.  Private?  Not in the least.  Lots of people here tell others to set their DNS servers to Google's (4.4.4.4 and 8.8.8.8).  You won't break anything, but all you're doing is giving Google another vector to log where you go.  Do you have a domain host you do business with because you could use their DNS.

Comment: @Allan I am not a tech guy. Where I should select DNS server? On a Mac network settings or in a router settings? And domain host you mean ISP?

Comment: In network settings, under "Advanced" is where you can set DNS servers.  Your ISP is one, but if you own a domain like "mydomain.com" you can use the DNS servers provided by the hosting company as well.  Cloudfare is fine - just know that any free service still comes with a cost and that cost is tracking where you go by the hosting provider.